# How to build a payload(POST method) in Square Brackets in C#, RestServices

Tags: c#, restsharp, xunit

**Expected Request:**

```
[
    {
        "ID": 159, //int
        "Name": "Sam", // String
        "Amount": 1    // int
    },
    {
        "ID": 160, //int
        "Name": "SamP", // String
        "Amount": 1    // int
    }
   ]
```

I have to build the request in that format But, I have some trouble with that square Brackets[] at the start and end of the payload

My approach on C#, RestServices, Xunit is like this:

**RestServices**

```
public IRestResponse PostIssue(IssueRequest IssueRequest, string Id)
    {
        var baseurl = _endpoint.EndpointURL;
        var resource = _refund.Issue;

        var restClient = new RestClient(baseurl);
        var request = new RestRequest(resource, Method.POST);

        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddQueryParameter("Id", Id);
        request.AddJsonBody(IssueRequest);

        // EXECUTE REQUEST
        var response = restClient.Execute(request);
        return response;
    }
```

**RequestModel:**

```
 public class IssueRequest
    {
        public Item[] IssueItem { get; set; }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
```

**XUnit Code:**

```
[Fact]
        public void IssueScenarios()
        {
            //Request Boody
            IssueRequest issueRequest = new IssueRequest
            {
                IssueItem = new Item[]
                {
                    new Item {Id = 159, Amount = 1, Name = "Sam"}
                    new Item {Id = 160, Amount = 1, Name = "Samp"}
                }
            };

            var response = _restServices.PostIssue(issueRequest, ItemID);
            IssueResponse parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<issueResponse>(response.Content);
}
```

Actually, I am able to build a payload like this:

```
{"Property1":[{"Id":159,"Amount":1,"Name":"Sam"},{"Id":160,"Amount":1,"Name":"SamP"}]}
```

but I need that to be like

```
[{"Id":159,"Amount":1,"Name":"Sam"},{"Id":160,"Amount":1,"Name":"SamP"}]
```

without any "Property1" name

Help is appreciated, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Serialize array of underlying items

```
request.AddJsonBody(IssueRequest.IssueItem);
```